# Как оптимизировать затраты памяти?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация, linq

**Дано:** БД MS SQL в которой есть таблица с координатами передвижения транспортных средств (Скорость, направление, широта долгота), а также таблица с данными о счётчиках, установленных в ТС (Плотность, объём, температура). Интерфейс реализован через WEB-приложение. Пользователь задаёт критерии отбора данных, по которым формируется выборка из БД.

**Цель:** Выгрузить данные из БД и преобразовать их в excel документ с минимальными затратами памяти.

**Проблема:** Во время обработки большого числа записей (больше 6000) операция прекращается (Предположительно, заканчивается место, выделенное CLR под память процесса)

**Код:**

```
public SLDocument ConvertGpsToExcel(List<GpsPoint> gpsNavigationList)
    {
        var documentSettings = new XmlDocumentMetaSettingsAdjustment();
        SLDocument slDocument = null;
        try
        {
            if (gpsNavigationList == null || !gpsNavigationList.Any())
                return null;

            // сортируем по дате создания gps поинта                
            gpsNavigationList = gpsNavigationList.OrderBy(x => x.GmtTime).ToList();
            var contentRowCount = gpsNavigationList.Count;
            // Получаем готовый для заполнения данными шаблон XML
            slDocument = documentSettings.GetStylishSLDocument(contentRowCount);
            // Сделал выборку данных из предварительно отсортированного листа GpsPoint
            var LevelDataList = gpsNavigationList.Select(x => x.EquipmentDatas).ToList();

            List<byte> CellId;
            List<float> Density, Level, Volume, Temperature;

            for (var i = 0; i<contentRowCount; i++)
            {
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 1, gpsNavigationList[i].Id.ToString());
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 2, gpsNavigationList[i].SerialNumber);

                CellId = LevelDataList[i].Select(x => x.CellId).ToList();
                Density = LevelDataList[i].Select(x => x.Density).ToList();
                Level = LevelDataList[i].Select(x => x.Level).ToList();
                Volume = LevelDataList[i].Select(x => x.Volume).ToList();
                Temperature = LevelDataList[i].Select(x => x.Temperature).ToList();
                // На больших объёмах информации может произойти сбой
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 3, CellId.Find(x => x == 1));
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 4, Density[CellId.Find(x => x == 1) - 1]); //Отнимаем один из-за сдвига относительно ноля (счёт ВСЕГДА начинается с 1)
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 5, Level[CellId.Find(x => x == 1) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 6, Volume[CellId.Find(x => x == 1) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 7, Temperature[CellId.Find(x => x == 1) - 1]);

                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 8, CellId.Find(x => x == 2));
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 9, Density[CellId.Find(x => x == 2) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 10, Level[CellId.Find(x => x == 2) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 11, Volume[CellId.Find(x => x == 2) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 12, Temperature[CellId.Find(x => x == 2) - 1]);

                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 13, CellId.Find(x => x == 3));
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 14, Density[CellId.Find(x => x == 3) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 15, Level[CellId.Find(x => x == 3) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 16, Volume[CellId.Find(x => x == 3) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 17, Temperature[CellId.Find(x => x == 3) - 1]);

                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 18, CellId.Find(x => x == 4));
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 19, Density[CellId.Find(x => x == 4) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 20, Level[CellId.Find(x => x == 4) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 21, Volume[CellId.Find(x => x == 4) - 1]);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 22, Temperature[CellId.Find(x => x == 3) - 1]);

                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 23, gpsNavigationList[i].Accuracy);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 24, gpsNavigationList[i].Speed);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 25, gpsNavigationList[i].Latitude);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(i + 2, 26, gpsNavigationList[i].Longitude);

            }

            slDocument.AutoFitColumn(1, 26);
            slDocument.AutoFitRow(1, contentRowCount + 1);

            return slDocument;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Освобождаем ресурсы:
            if (slDocument != null)
            {
                _eventLogManager.LogEvent($"Ошибка при выполнении блока try в ConvertGpsToExcel! \nslDocument = null!");
                slDocument.CloseWithoutSaving();
                slDocument.Dispose();
            }
            _eventLogManager.LogError(e.Message);
            return null;
        }            
    }
```

**Моё мнение:** очень много памяти уходит на инициализацию List'ов при каждой итерации. Ожидаю, что можно обойтись без их инициализации, воспользовавшись ухищрённым LINQ-запросом для нахождения точного значения из передаваемого списка. (Я не смог догадаться)

Собственно говоря, проблема в составлении этого запроса (если возможно)

Comment: В показанном коде нет работы с БД. Оптимизировать нечего.

Comment: 6000 записей для пк — это вообще ни о чем, если у вас там не мегабайт на одну запись

Comment: И операции прост о так не прекращаются, ищите текст ошибки

Comment: _очень много памяти уходит на инициализацию List'ов при каждой итерации_ - ну да. Не используйте LINQ. Используйте простые циклы `for/foreach`. Перед началом цикла создайте списки и добавляйте в них данные методом `Add`. В конце очищайте их методом `Clear()`.

Comment: _Предположительно, заканчивается место, выделенное CLR под память процесса_ - текст исключения в студию. `e.Message`. 6000 записей - это мелочь, 600 миллионов я бы еще понял. Покажите класс `GpsPoint`.

Comment: Действительно, проблема была в неграмотном использовании LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что вернет из `List<byte>` код `CellId.Find(x => x == 2)` - "найди мне элемент со значением 2", конечно же 2! Ну и смысл тогда этих поисков?

Без структур данных тут вменяемое что-то сложно посоветовать, но вслепую получилось вот так:

```
public SLDocument ConvertGpsToExcel(List<GpsPoint> gpsNavigationList)
{
    if (gpsNavigationList == null || !gpsNavigationList.Any())
        return null;

    SLDocument slDocument = null;
    try
    {
        // сортируем по дате создания gps поинта
        gpsNavigationList.Sort((x, y) => x.GmtTime.CompareTo(y.GmtTime));

        int contentRowCount = gpsNavigationList.Count;
        var documentSettings = new XmlDocumentMetaSettingsAdjustment();
        slDocument = documentSettings.GetStylishSLDocument(contentRowCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < contentRowCount; i++)
        {
            var gpsNavigationItem = gpsNavigationList[i];
            var levelDataItem = gpsNavigationItem.EquipmentDatas;
            int row = i + 2;
            int column = 1;
            slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, gpsNavigationItem.Id.ToString());
            slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, gpsNavigationItem.SerialNumber);

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                var equipmentData = levelDataItem[j];
                slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, j + 1);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, equipmentData.Density);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, equipmentData.Level);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, equipmentData.Volume);
                slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, equipmentData.Temperature);
            }

            slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, gpsNavigationItem.Accuracy);
            slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, gpsNavigationItem.Speed);
            slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column++, gpsNavigationItem.Latitude);
            slDocument.SetCellValue(row, column, gpsNavigationItem.Longitude);
        }

        slDocument.AutoFitColumn(1, 26);
        slDocument.AutoFitRow(1, contentRowCount + 1);

        return slDocument;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (slDocument != null)
        {
            _eventLogManager.LogEvent($"Ошибка при выполнении блока try в ConvertGpsToExcel!");
            slDocument.CloseWithoutSaving();
            slDocument.Dispose();
        }
        _eventLogManager.LogError(e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Теперь должно 6000 строк проглотить за долю секунуды. Никакой дополнительной памяти теперь вообще не выделяется. Стоит заметить, что Linq оказался совсем не нужен.

Повторяющийся код - это всегда плохо, используйте циклы и разбивку по методам, чтобы избежать повторяющегося кода.

Кстати, я бы на вашем месте не страдал бы с XLS файлами, а просто выгрузился бы в CSV. Excel их умеет кушать, и не только Excel.

Comment: Спасибо! Это как раз то, что мне нужно! С вашим кодом всё работает!